# PySpark group by to return constant if all values are negative but average if only some are

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = 
+----+-----+
|Year|Value|
+----+-----+
|   1|   50|
|   1|   30|
|   1|   20|
|   2|  -14|
|   2|  -34|
|   3|   10|
|   3|   20|
|   3|  -34|
+----+-----+
```

I want to group by Year and show the average of value. If the Value column is negative I want to ignore that unless all the values of a particular year are negative (year = 2). Then I just want to show avg(Value) as -1.

I am doing:

```
df.filter(df.Value > 0).groupBy('Year').agg(avg('Value').alias('Average')).show()
```

which gives me this

```
+----+------------------+
|Year|           Average|
+----+------------------+
|   1|33.333333333333336|
|   3|              15.0|
+----+------------------+
```

The result I want is

```
+----+------------------+
|Year|           Average|
+----+------------------+
|   1|33.333333333333336|
|   2|                -1|
|   3|              15.0|
+----+------------------+
```

Anyone has any idea how to achieve the above result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the negative values in the `Value` column with `null`, and then use group by and compute average.
`avg` ignores `nulls`, which is what you need. In the end, I'm replacing `null` averages with `-1`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, when, col

df.withColumn("Value", when(col("Value") < 0, None).otherwise(col("Value")))\
    .groupBy('Year').agg(avg('Value').alias('Average'))\
    .fillna(-1, subset=['Average']).show()

+----+------------------+
|Year|           Average|
+----+------------------+
|   1|33.333333333333336|
|   2|              -1.0|
|   3|              15.0|
+----+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. This is exactly what I needed. One follow-up question. Let's say there is another column - [Flag] of type String. Now I want to replace the [Value] column with None and take average if [Value] < 0 OR [Flag] is not empty. I wrote this and it works: ```df.withColumn("Value", when(col("Value") < 0, None).when(col("Flag") != "", None).otherwise(col("Value")))\
    .groupBy('Year').agg(avg('Value').alias('Average')).fillna(-1, subset=['Average']).show()```. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your code looks good. I don't see any other way that can provide significantly better performance.